# Set-Cookie header not creating cookie in test environment

Tags: php, angular, cookies, setcookie

I have a local testing application mimicking the host `test.mywebsite.com` on port 4200.

It makes a call to `api.test.mywebsite.com` (also locally hosted) to `/login`

The request passes, the server returns 200 and some information, and along with it it sets this header which I see in the response headers:

```
Set-Cookie: refreshToken={JWT here}; expires=Sun, 23-May-2021 20:38:32 GMT; Max-Age=1296000; path=/; domain=.test.mywebsite.com; HttpOnly
```

This doesn't get stored in my browser (either Chrome or Firefox) and I'm trying to figure out why.

Here's some more information about my setup if needed:
Angular server using `ng serve --host=test.mywebsite.com` to get the test frontend up on `http://test.mywebsite.com:4200`

Kubernetes backend running on `localhost` (with my hosts file redirecting `api.test.mywebsite.com` to `127.0.0.1`) which directs the request to a PHP pod that creates the cookie using this code:

```php
     setcookie(
        "refreshToken",          // name
        $refreshJWT->token,      // token
        $refreshJWT->expiration, // expires in 15 days
        '/',                     // path
        ".".$refreshJWT->domain, // domain
        ($refreshJWT->environmentType === "test") ? false : true, // security
        true                     // httponly
    );
```

I fear it's something painfully simple or an oversight somewhere, but can't for the life of me find out what. The only thing I can think of would be the port not matching with the cookie host, but as far as I know cookie domains are port-agnostic. I've tried adding `:4200` to the end of the cookie domain anyway and still have the same problem.

Update: setcookie() returns true, so there's no output previous to setting the header.

Update2: I deployed it to a staging server and the problem still occurs despite no DNS trickery or proxies going on.

Update3: I've narrowed it down to a combination of my api server's `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, and my JS' use of `withCredentials`
My `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set to `*`. If I send the request `withCredentials` as `false`, it returns the body to the JS but refuses the cookie. If I set `withCredentials` to true, it sets the cookie but refuses to allow the JS to read the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the reason, for anyone who may be stumbling on this:

The first problems was while my requests were going through and returning 200, the cookie was not being set because I didn't agree to receive a cookie on the frontend. To agree to cookies on the frontend, I had to use [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials).

The second problem was on the backend, I didn't explicitly send the header [Access-Control-Allow-Credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials) This would allow both front and backend to agree to a cookie exchange.

The third problem was my backend had a wildcard set for [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin), which my browser requires to match the current host exactly if `withCredentials` is used.

Answer (score 1):

> It makes a call to api.test.mywebsite.com

...

> domain=.test.mywebsite.com

These need to be the same hostname

Comment: Ah good catch. Unfortunately I've changed the cookie hostname to be `.api.test.mywebsite.com` and it still doesn't seem to be storing or attaching the cookies to subsequent requests made to `api.test.mywebsite.com`

Comment: Now that I look deeper into it, why do they need to be the same hostname? [RFC2109](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) gives the example that `* A Set-Cookie from request-host x.foo.com for Domain=.foo.com would be accepted.` Does that not apply here?

Comment: Is it so hard to test?

Comment: As I said in the first comment, I've tested it and it doesn't work.